# Are REP instructions considered vector operations?

Tags: assembly, x86, simd

I am trying to understand the concepts of SIMD and vector instructions.
If I understand correctly:

- Vector instructions are instructions that operate on a one dimensional array of data (=vector), as opposed to scalar instructions which operate on a single data item.
- SIMD instructions are actually Single Instruction Multiple Data instructions which seem like the same thing as vector instruction... I don't really know the difference and if there is any..

REP instructions operate on an array of data, therefore it seems like they are actually SIMD/vector instructions. I haven't seen any article describing them as vector instructions, and I know that REP instructions are not part of the SIMD extensions of x86.

My questions are:

1. Is REP considered a vector operation?
2. Is REP considered a SIMD instruction?
3. Is there any actual difference between vector and SIMD instructions?

---

A quick google search for my third question led me to this:

> Vector-processing architectures are now considered separate from SIMD computers, based on the fact that vector computers processed the vectors one word at a time through pipelined processors (though still based on a single instruction), whereas modern SIMD computers process all elements of the vector simultaneously.

In actual articles I've read I haven't seen the mentioned difference, and the vector and SIMD terms were used interchangeably, so that what led me to think that there is no actual difference...

Comment: are you talking about x86?  if so tag it and remove the rep tag or are you talking about what is listed in the rep tag?  if it is the x86 instruction then it is not about arrays it is about repeating the next instruction some number of times, which is often done in order to work through a chunk of data, but I would call it a stretch to try to attach a vector label to it.  stop worrying about labels like vector.  in general their definition is within the reader, so each user/reader of a term like that has a different definition.

Comment: if it is an x86 thing then look at intels documentation and if they have a chapter or section titled vector instructions then only the instructions in that chapter are vector instructions as far as that term goes within that context.

Comment: I know it is not referenced as SIMD or vector instruction in the documentation, I just don't know why, as it does answer the description of these types of instructions.

Comment: Oh OK I see... you say that REP instruction is not specially intended for vector operations (although it is often used for it), so it is not a 'real' vector (or SIMD) instruction but it CAN be used for vectors just like regular vector instructions. Am I correct?

Comment: `rep` is not an instruction.  It is a prefix, and cannot be used by itself.  It was part of the original 8086 CPU, well before SIMD became commonplace.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn%27s_taxonomy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Vector" and "SIMD" mean much the same thing, but in common usage the terms typically point to different implementation approaches.  This distinction derives from the history of the terms in computing.  Both "vector" and "SIMD" instruction sets are based on the concept of performing the same operation on multiple data elements in cases for which there are no data dependencies **within** the sequence of operations.  When there are no data dependencies, the operations can be performed in any order, including simultaneously.

Historically, "vector" is the older term, and "vector" instructions are thought of as single instructions that perform some operation on a sequence of elements by pipelining the operations through a single functional unit.  The "single functional unit" has nothing to do with vectorization as a concept -- it was the way vector machines were implemented when transistors were very expensive (mid-1960s through mid-1990s).  More recent "vector" architectures use a single vector instruction to pipeline operation across multiple functional units.  E.g., the NEC SX-Aurora TSUBASA processor has 256-element vector registers and 32 vector functional units, with each 256-element vector sending 8 elements to each vector functional unit.

I don't know when the term "SIMD" was first used, but I don't recall seeing it in common use before the mid-1990s, when "SIMD" instructions were first developed as a means of performing multiple parallel operations on smaller data sizes within **existing** register widths.  For example, the Intel MMX instruction set (1997) enables the processor to perform independent 8/16/32-bit operations on the contents of a 64-bit register. Later SIMD instruction sets (SSE, etc) provide new registers that are wider than any single supported data type, to allow operation on independent fields up to 64 bits wide within the register.   The design of the instruction set **supports** simultaneous operation of the operations across the entire SIMD register width, but this is not required.  AMD, for example, has produced several generations of processors that support instructions on wider SIMD registers than the parallelism of the functional units.  E.g., AMD's first-generation EPYC processors support 256-bit SIMD instructions, but these are dispatched to 128-bit-wide functional units over two consecutive cycles.  ARM's Scalable Vector Extensions further decouple the concepts of vector width and number of parallel functional units.

The "REP" instructions in the x86 architecture provide a limited ability to provide vector-like functionality for the "string instructions" and "in/out" instructions.  They are not a general mechanism, and I am sure that many of the Intel processor designers wish they could have been dropped from the instruction set.   Some interesting historical notes are in the forum discussion at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/275765

Comment: So in [this article](https://www.sigarch.org/simd-instructions-considered-harmful/) by David Patterson, when he compares SIMD and vector processing he actually talks about implementation approach differences? If I understand correctly, he uses the term **SIMD** to describe an approach of using a single register for a vector (by partitioning it), and the term **vector processing** to describe the approach of using separate registers for the vector items (instead of a single one), and then he considers the SIMD approach as harmful. Am I wrong?

Comment: @YAYAdest: Yup, that's about right.  And yes, Patterson does consider modern CPU-style short-vector SIMD like x86 SSE/AVX and ARM NEON "harmful", I think because it's hard to use and/or often under-utilized, I forget his exact reasoning.  But until someone invents a better way to get as much work per clock cycle through the instruction pipeline, we're stuck with it.  "Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the others".  GPU-style computing (also called SIMD but very different from CPU-style short-vectors) is different and only usable for massively parallel problems.

Comment: Worth mentioning that although `repe/ne scas/cmps` implement memchr / memmem (i.e. explicit-length string search/compare), they're not *efficient* on modern CPUs.  Like 1 cycle per repeat, same as a naive non-SIMD loop.  Only the non-conditional `rep movs/stos` memcpy / memset operations have microcode that uses wide loads/stores (the same functional units as SIMD) for large repeat counts, and there's still significant startup overhead.  It is very nice for kernel code, though, which can't use SIMD without saving/restoring the SIMD register state.

Comment: Patterson's article emphasizes the role of a programmable "vector length" in the static and dynamic instruction counts.   The RISC-V Vector Extension (and the ARM Scalable Vector Extension) decouple the vector length from the number of functional units (as I mentioned above), but also provide features that allow a single loop to handle many different vector lengths and alignments. I would call these approaches intermediate between the "traditional" vector instruction sets and SIMD instruction sets.

Comment: Oh right, yeah one of the biggest problems with x86 SIMD is that you need to recompile (or even redo manual vectorization) to take advantage of wider hardware, like AVX and AVX512.  And low-power Intel CPUs (Atom/Silvermont) can't support any of the nice new AVX or AVX512 instructions (like unsigned <-> float conversion) unless they also handled 512-bit vectors.  Exposing pipeline internals in the ISA can help in the short term but then later CPUs are stuck running old binaries that don't match their pipeline anymore.  I think Patterson learned this lesson with MIPS branch-delay slots. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes So you say that `rep movs/stos`  in current implementation actually uses SIMD's functional units, which as I understand makes it not far from a 'regular' SIMD instruction (although it is not mentioned as SIMD in Intel's documentation). It also answers my question: `rep movs/stos` _can_ behave like a SIMD/vector instruction, but it is not considered as such.

Comment: @YAYAdest: yes, `rep movs/stos` microcode is I think somewhat like old-style Cray long variable-length vector computing.  But unfortunately the current implementations are microcoded, not a hardware state machine, and have significant startup overhead making them less good for small problems.  In code like a standard-library memset / memcpy that can get updated for later ISA extensions as you upgrade the OS, SIMD load/store instructions like `movdqa xmm` or `vmovdqa ymm` or even `zmm` are usually a better choice on current HW.